# Change default form for field in django

Tags: python, django

I'm programming an application in Django and I have a ManyToManyField in my model, this relates a User model with Event model, but when I enter in django admin, the default form for ManyToManyField show all User registered in mi DB, I can't select the user that I want select.

¿ How I can change the default form in the admin site for a select form ?

This is what i have:

[image]

and I want something like this:

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) in your Admin class for this model.

That would be something like:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  filter_horizontal = ('participantes',)
```